# When using StreamWriter Async I get the error "The stream is currently in use by a previous operation on the stream"

Tags: c#, async-await, semaphore, streamwriter

I have a set of tasks that get strings that I am trying to coordinate into a stream. It all looks good, but in practice I am getting a

> The stream is currently in use by a previous operation on the stream

after a `Task.WhenAll` call.

Example:

```
    private readonly List<Task<string>> _objectData = new List<Task<string>>();
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _writerSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

    private async Task SafelyWrite(StreamWriter streamWriter, string field)
    {
        await _writerSemaphore.WaitAsync();

        if (field.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
        {
            return;
        }

        streamWriter.Write(field);

        await streamWriter.FlushAsync();

        _writerSemaphore.Release();
    }

    public override async Task Build(StreamWriter streamWriter)
    {
        streamWriter.Write('{');

        await Task.WhenAll(
            _objectData.Select(async str => SafelyWrite(streamWriter, await str)));

        // await Task.Delay(10);

        // If I don't wait for a few milliseconds the app
        // will throw an error on this line that the stream
        // is currently being written to?
        streamWriter.Write('}');

        await streamWriter
            .FlushAsync();
    }
```

With or without the delay if I look at the contents of the stream, it's all valid. Everything has finished, it's just that the `StreamWriter` thinks it hasn't? If I wait for a few milliseconds, the `StreamWriter` thinks everything HAS finished and I can write the closing block.

Is there something between the `Task.WhenAll` and the `SemaphoreSlim` that I am missing?

(Sorry for the volume of code, it seemed like the minimum failing, but usefully complete, example)

Comment: Your SafelyWrite isn't so safe. Don't you care about the order of the outputs?

Comment: When you FlushAsync then also WriteAsync.

Comment: Aside from the valid point @HenkHolterman makes above - given that each task has to access the stream sequentially I dont imagine there is any real benefit from running them concurrently. Have you considered removing the semaphore and awaiting each task sequentially in a loop?

Comment: Your `SafelyWrite` method is assuming a protocol for safely accessing the stream (e.g. using the semaphore) that your `Build` method doesn't. It's hardly surprising when two different bits of code don't agree on the protocol for accessing an exclusive resource, problems arise.

Comment: I don't want the other tasks waiting around for something else to be finished before writing and I want the data from the task to be cleaned up as quickly as possible (aka, after it's been written to the stream garbage collected).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I don't think I understand what you mean there by 'protocol' could you clarify?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your over thinking this. What makes you think your "tasks waiting around" is having any kind of performance bottle neck?

Comment: @Liam I have profiled the code in both a synchronous and coordinated async way, and the volume of data we are processing means that in the sync operation we are spiking memory (we are talking possibly 100sMB of data), using the coordinated streaming, we can be aggressive about cleaning up, once the data is available. I appreciate it might be complex, but still, would like to know why this issue occurs when the APIs used, say it shouldn't.

Comment: async/await is typically about CPU/thread utilisation, not memory. I'd say increasing this is more likely to **increase your memory usage** not decrease it. Your current code is blocking anyway (`SemaphoreSlim(1, 1)`), so it's not even doing that. There is no point in your `Task.WhenAll`, etc. stuff here. Because your pretending it's not blocking, then blocking on write/flush. I'm pretty sure your barking up the wrong tree here

Comment: `_objectData` is the smoking gun to your issue (as I understand it) here. I presume this is reading from something. So your reading something, turn this into a load of in memory strings (guessing large strings) then streaming these out. It'd be more efficient to pipe the read stream directly into the write stream and clean/dispose of both of these as you go without using `string`s (and the associated memory allocations) at all. But that's a different question

Comment: @Liam my desire is, to spawn all the data retrieval tasks concurrently, so they can be more readily parallelised, then write (process) the data as soon as they are complete. Trying to balance writing directly to stream when data available (mem) and parallelised retrieval (time). I couldn't think of a better pattern, am very open to suggestion though.

Comment: @Liam, yeah the string issue is a whole other thing, but those I am stuck with, for now.

Comment: First thing that jumps out in your statements above, there is **nothing parallel** in this code. This code will only ever use a single thread at any one time. This code is **asynchronous** not parallel. For it to be parallel you would need to spawn `Task`s using `Task.Run()`. Parallel uses additional threads to complete task in a shorter time frame (CPU bound), async uses the same thread to offload IO bound processes and utilise that thread more efficiently. Both consume additional CPU resource. Tl;Dr I think you need to do more research on what your planning here.

Comment: A good question to ask yourself here is where is the bottle neck, the "data retrieval" or the "write(ing) (process) the data"? My guess is the "data retrieval" as writing s single file should be fast. So why not get all your data asynchronously, then wait for them all to return (`await Task.WhenAll()`) then write them after this returns. This is all guess work you need to do some bench marking

Comment: Is this a multi threaded environment too? You also need to be wary of robing peter to pay paul. If you make your one process super efficient but in doing so you use large amounts of CPU then all the other processes suffer from CPU starvation, so you need to load test too.

Comment: @Liam the environment is multi-threaded and the code above is somewhat simplified. The operations are happening in parallel. For now as it seems nobody can tell me why there is a delay to the stream thinking async operations are occuring and the end of an await block, I have pulled back to waiting for all the data retrieval tasks and (a)synchronously writing to the stream. I have the `StreamWriter` source though and will debug when I have more time.

Comment: What Damien is getting at is this line from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=netframework-4.7.2): "By default, a StreamWriter is not thread safe." `SafelyWrite` is protecting access with the `SemaphoreSlim` but the other writes are *not* using that same semaphore.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of justification of applying such approach for writing data to a stream the problem here in the fact that there is place where you just "fire and forget" asynchronous tasks. In particular if you take a look at the `_objectData.Select(async str => SafelyWrite(streamWriter, await str))` precisely  you'll see that here is enumerator which inside initiates the awaiting of `str` tasks but doesn't actually await for the completion of these processes on the higher level. So instead of

```
await Task.WhenAll(_objectData.Select(async str => SafelyWrite(streamWriter, await str)));
```

there should be

```
await Task.WhenAll((await Task.WhenAll(_objectData)).Select(str => SafelyWrite(streamWriter, str)));
```

Just to add readability and in order to avoid misinterpretation for the second option here is its equivalent:

```
var results = await Task.WhenAll(_objectData);
var writeTasks = results.Select(str => SafelyWrite(streamWriter, str));
await Task.WhenAll(writeTasks);
```

Comment: I think this has very different behaviour. The first line returns a list of tasks, that what the async/await keywords do, that are then awaited by the `Task.WhenAll`. The second awaits the list of tasks, then creates a new list of tasks from `SafelyWrite`, which are awaited. I wanted to avoid retrieving all the data, then streaming them one by one. In your second case the call to safely write is just a very complex way of writing a for loop.

Comment: They are different of course and the first one is incorrect. When you write `await str` who is supposed to wait for completeness of this task on the higher level? The second option isn't loop - it's just a two-phases process which are sequential to each other (data retrieval and data writing) with asynchronous tasks inside.